# How can I work towards removing an answer ban from 1 bad answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, privileges

I was browsing some questions and wanted to answer some. As I couldn't comment, I made an answer on a post which was more like a comment, which got downvoted and deleted.

I am ok with that, my 'answer' wasn't an answer and *should* be deleted. (not ok with the fact that I cant help the one that made the question). I also have a Stack Overflow account, so I already know when to answer and when to comment.

After that, Arqade informs me that I have 0 answers that have lots of downvotes, and that I cannot answer more questions until I fix those 0 answers.

In order to post here, I HAD to create a question (yes, it was hard, I had to think anything that someone would like to know to vote it up).

When I received the ban, I got

> Your block was triggered automatically by the system; most of your posts have not been well-received by the community - meaning they were either downvoted or not voted on at all.
>
> We cannot lift posting blocks – you must improve your existing posts in order for the system to allow you to participate further. You are able to edit your posts. When you do, they move to the top of the queue, allowing the community the chance to upvote them.

But in my situation:

- "*most of your posts*" is 1 post, and that 1 post got deleted, only moderators can see it.
- "*you must improve your existing post*" is 0 post at all.
- "*you are able to edit your posts*" No, I am not able to edit my only post.

How am I supposed to be able to help, without first asking a question in order to get some reputation and recover the answer privileges?

Comment: I see multiple deleted answers on your main site Arqade account. Also, I don't see a current posting ban on your account - looks like you have gotten yourself out of whatever issues you were experiencing. A third point - it does take any deleted answers either by yourself or others into account.

Comment: Ashley as i said, i had to create a question, so i unlifted my ban by that way, also, i couldnt see my deleted answers on my account, until ardaozkal give me the link to see it directly.

Comment: Just a small note: The different Stack sites handle situations differently from one another. For example: whilst answers on Stack Overflow might get converted to comments more often, on Arqade that rarely happens, and only for 'answers' which a) don't answer the question and b) are valuable enough to keep. I bring this up because 'answering' as a workaround to the '50 rep' comment restriction is frowned upon here, whereas on other sites it might not be seen as so bad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hello, welcome to Arqade and sorry that you are going through this.

First of all, just saying: moderators can't unblock you.

You should post well-received questions to get unblocked. The amount reportedly varies by the amount of downvotes you got.

Also, your post has some problematic parts, so let me explain them:

> "most of your posts" is 1 post.

If it got enough downvotes, it is enough to get you blocked.

> That 1 post got deleted, only moderators could see it.

People over 10k rep can see it too. Also, if you open the question you replied to, you'll be able to see your answer in red tint, saying that it was removed.

> "you must improve your existing post" is 0 post at all.

and

> "you are able to edit your posts" No, iam not able to edit my only post.

As I stated, you can see your answer by opening the question you replied to. You can undelete it (< I don't recommend doing that before editing it, as you might get more downvotes etc.) or edit it too.

Hope you get unblocked and help us in this community!

If you have further questions, feel free to drop by [our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), you appear to have enough reputation to do so!

Comment: Thanks i didnt know i could get to see the deleted answers, the problem is that those ansers do not appaer in my profile page:http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/106420/gaunt?tab=answers

Comment: @Gaunt try clicking here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/106420

Answer (score 3):

Note that you intentionally cannot comment without enough reputation. This can be frustrating, because you might have the most appropriate comment to add but unable to do so. In this situation, all you can do is walk away and attempt to gain reputation. Optionally you could *favourite* the question (or bookmark it) for when you do have enough reputation, and it might be still relevant to comment on.

Although you are a member on Stack Overflow as well, the site doesn't *trust* you enough yet to grant you small privileges by default. [Once you have 200 reputation on any Stack Exchange account, associating your account with another site will grant you +100 reputation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) (or having an already-associated account) which gives you [basic privileges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) so you'd be able to comment anywhere, flag and vote up.

So how are you suppose to help when you have no reputation? Unfortunately, you can't. You need to gain reputation so the system trusts that you are helping. The more reputation you have, the system assumes you are more trustworthy at knowing what's on/off-topic, spam etc. If the system allowed any user with 1 reputation to vote up/down, flag comments etc, the site would probably be far worse.

Comment: *"had you over 200 reputation on Stack Overflow, when signing up here you'd have started with 101 reputation"* - I'm pretty sure the +100 rep is retroactive, i.e. if Gaunt gets to 200 rep on SO, all existing associated accounts (such as Arqade) will also get +100, regardless of when he signed up

Comment: i can confirm that this is indeed accurate @Robotnik it happened to me, just i got my 200+ rep on arqade as opposed to SO