# Are game-specific answers to general terminology questions discouraged?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In terminology questions, is it discouraged to explain how the fandom of one particular game has decided to use a particular term?

Here's the gist of an answer that I gave ([10k](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/256843/69014)) that has been fairly heavily downvoted:

> Q: What's the difference between a bug and a glitch?
>
> A: It differs among fandoms. The fandom of one game series that contains "bugs" (insects) uses the term "glitch" more broadly than other fandoms might in order to avoid confusion. Here are my sources.

What should I do to improve this answer so that I don't have one [strike on my permanent record](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11328/how-can-i-work-towards-removing-an-answer-ban-from-1-bad-answer), plus however many strikes whatever [old deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) I have (if any) are worth?

Comment: Down votes are only worth - 2. Answer up votes are worth +10, questions are worth +5. So I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: @AshleyNunn It's not the rep as much as the threat of a [ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) that I'm worried about.

Comment: Trust me, one question isn't going to make that much of a difference.

Answer (score 4):

**Why I downvoted**

Answers need to fully answer the question, not just provide trivia.

In this case, you gave one example which was tangentially relevant to the discussion. It could have been useful to include in a complete answer but, as it is, it is not useful. Alternatively, those claims could have been posted as a comment.

**How to deal with it**

Don't worry about it.

One bad answer will not undo 700 rep worth of helpful posts. It's extremely unlikely you'll get your posts limited, much less banned.

You can get your rep back by deleting your answer. There is no shame in doing this; we even offer a medal for it. Deleting your own bad answer won't cause any sanctions on your account unless you're trying to abuse this, e.g. by reposting the answer with the votes removed.